# Java Game Loop Help-updates per second vs frames per second

Tags: java, game-loop

Assuming I use this game loop and want to maintain 60 FPS, what would be the appropriate UPS (updates per second)?  Should it be 60 as well?  Thanks for any help

```
  @Override
public void run() {

long initialTime = System.nanoTime();
final double timeU = 1000000000 / UPS;
final double timeF = 1000000000 / FPS;
double deltaU = 0, deltaF = 0;
int frames = 0, ticks = 0;
long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();

    while (running) {

        long currentTime = System.nanoTime();
        deltaU += (currentTime - initialTime) / timeU;
        deltaF += (currentTime - initialTime) / timeF;
        initialTime = currentTime;

        if (deltaU >= 1) {
            getInput();
            update();
            ticks++;
            deltaU--;
        }

        if (deltaF >= 1) {
            render();
            frames++;
            deltaF--;
        }

        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
            if (RENDER_TIME) {
                System.out.println(String.format("UPS: %s, FPS: %s", ticks, frames));
            }
            frames = 0;
            ticks = 0;
            timer += 1000;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your update rate does not have to be the same as your frame rate. Use whatever rate works for your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Update should be fixed

```
double previous = getCurrentTime();
double lag = 0.0;


    while (true) {

        double current = getCurrentTime();
        double elapsed = current - previous;
        previous = current;
        lag += elapsed;

        processInput();

        while (lag >= MS_PER_UPDATE) {
            update();
            lag -= MS_PER_UPDATE;
        }

        render();
}
```

If the difference between the real time and the game time is higher than wanted time between two updates you have to update.
If lag is lower it means you dont have to update yet but you can render anyway.

Better explanation here: http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html